# Получить выборку пользователей у которых сегодня день рождения

Tags: php, mysql

Есть база данных, где хранятся все зарегистрированные пользователи. Есть поле дата рождения. Как получить все записи у которых сегодня день рождения? Я сделал что могу получить записи если он родился в этот день включая год

```
$today = date("d.m.Y"); 

$users = $this->pages_model->get_users();

foreach ($users as $item){
  $result=(strtotime($item['birthday'])==strtotime($today));
    if ($result){
      echo $item['fio'];
    }
}
```

Но Мне нужно получить записи, что если у него день рождения 19.05.1988 он тоже получил эту запись.

Все бы ничего, можно было поиграть с запросом но поле `$item['birthday']` в mySQL не типа `date`, а `varchar`.

Как быть?

Comment: Язык SQL придуман для того, чтобы манипулировать множествами. Печально видеть, когда эта его особенность игнорируется, а обработка перекладывается на скриптовый язык типа php. Это **очень** неоптимально.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почините базу – пусть поле `birthday` станет датой – поможет функция [`STR_TO_DATE(str,format)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).

И выбирайте из базы только тех юзеров, у которых сегодня день рождения:

```
SELECT *
FROM `users`
WHERE
  MONTH(`birthday`) = MONTH(NOW)
  AND
  DAYOFMONTH(`birthday`) = DAYOFMONTH(`NOW`)
```

Comment: А можно саму структуру поменять? что бы все записи переконвертировались

Comment: В каком формате там сейчас даты?  Если что-то понятное MySQL, напр. `1990-12-03`, можно попробовать сделать `ALTER TABLE users CHANGE birthday birthday DATE NOT NULL; `

Answer (score 0):

```
select date_format(str_to_date('12/31/2011', '%m/%d/%Y'), '%Y%m');
```

Можете преобразовать ваш **varchar to date** и получить его с помощью запроса. Далее обработать и все будет хорошо.